# Codeigniter 4 sum many columns in multiple join table throwing wrong results

Tags: mysql, join, sum, codeigniter-4, multi-table

I am doing my first project using Codeigniter 4. I am trying to make a summary page which consist of some sum from different columns and different tables.

Here is the tables :

table project

| id | project_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | project 1 |
| 2 | project 2 |

table leading
| id | id_project | permit | job |
| -- | ---------- |--------| ----
| 1  | 1          | 2      | 2   |
| 2  | 1          | 2      | 2   |
| 3  | 2          | 1      | 1   |

table man_hours
| id | id_project | branch | base | sum_manhours |
| -- | ---------- |--------| ---- | ------------ |
| 1  | 1          | 1      | 2    | 3            |
| 2  | 1          | 1      | 2    | 3            |
| 3  | 2          | 1      | 1    | 2            |

I've tried this :

ProjectModel :

```
    public function getSummary()
    {

        $this->join('leading', 'leading.id_project=project.id', 'LEFT');
        $this->join('man_hours', 'man_hours.id_project=project.id', 'LEFT');
        $this->select('sum(permit) as permit, sum(job) as job');
        $this->select('sum(sum_manhours) as sum_manhours');
        $this->select('project.id, project.project_name');
        $this->groupBy('project.id');
        $result = $this->findAll();

        return $result;
    }
```

Controller Project :

```
public function manhours(){
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Summary',
            'project' => $this->projectModel->getSummary()
        ];

        return view('summary/view-summary-manhours', $data);
}
```

The results :

| no | project name | permit | leading | sum_manhours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8 | 8 | 12 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

It seems like the query working twice that's why is giving the wrong results, how do I fix this?
I am really looking forward for the solution, thank you so much for reading my question, even more for giving me solution.

Comment: Please share the responses of: `show create table project;` , `show create table leading;` , and `show create table man_hours;` ln addition,  share your expected results (behavior).

Comment: I created the tables directly on mysql database using mamp phpmyadmin. Here is the Model of each table :

ProjectModel :
`    protected $table = 'project';
    protected $useTimestamps = true;
    protected $returnType     = 'array';
    protected $allowedFields = ['project_name', 'location'];`

LeadingModel :
`protected $table = 'leading';
protected $useTimestamps = true;
protected $returnType     = 'array';
protected $allowedFields = [
    'id_user', 'id_project', 'date', 'permit', 'job'
];`

Comment: ManhoursModel : 
`protected $table = 'man_hours';
protected $useTimestamps = true;
protected $returnType     = 'array';
protected $allowedFields = [
    'id_user', 'id_project', 'date', 'branch', 'base', 'sum_manhours'
];`

Comment: expected result for column project 1 the sum of permit and job should be 4 and sum of sum_manhours should be 6, but it gives twice of the sum amount.

Comment: When in development mode it shows the generated and executed SQL-query in the debug toolbar under `Database`. Could you post that here?

Comment: Run the SQL queries from my comment in your PHPMyAdmin application and share the output/response.

Comment: Hi @steven7mwesigwa how do i share the screenshot here? I am sorry this is my first time asking in stackoverflow.